# Android - put data into array in asynctask

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-studio, android-asynctask

I got a question that I don't know how to solve.

I am trying to achieve putting the 'question' and 'answer' into the 2D Array, but it cannot put the data into the 2D array in the `asyncTask`.

I am expecting I can put the 'question' and 'answer' that get in JSON Object into the 2D array. And then use the array in `OnCreate` method.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    String[][] array = new String[10][4];
    private TextView tvData;
    int qnum = 1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String quest;
        String ans;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new JSONTask().execute("http://itdmoodle.hung0530.com/ptms/questions_ws.php");
        Button btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        tvData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            int z = i+1;
            array[i][0] = String.valueOf(z);
        }
        quest = array[0][1];
        ans = array[0][2];
        tvData.setText(quest);
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });
    }
    public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            try{
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.connect();
                InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                String line ="";
                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    buffer.append(line);
                }
                String Json = buffer.toString();
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(Json);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Questions");
                StringBuffer bufferQues = new StringBuffer();
                StringBuffer bufferAns = new StringBuffer();
                for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++) {
                    JSONObject otherJson = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String question = otherJson.getString("question");
                    String answer = otherJson.getString("answer");
                    bufferQues.append(question);
                    bufferAns.append(answer);
                    array[i][1] = bufferQues.toString();
                    array[i][2] = bufferAns.toString();
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally{
                if(conn != null){
                    conn.disconnect();
                }
                try{
                    if(reader != null){
                        reader.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be better if instead of uploading pictures of your code you type the code. Editor provides formatting options for codes.

Comment: I am sorry that I did't know how to type the code when I asking a question

Comment: Edit your question, remove the images, copy paste your code, select your code and click Ctrl+k (cmd+k if you are using mac).

Answer (score 0):

Asynctask executes asynchronously. It allows you to perform long running operations on a background thread(doInBackground is run on a seperate thread than main thread) and use the results to perform operations on main thread(onPostExecute runs on main thread).
What you want is to perform the operation on your 2D array in onPostExecute and not in onCreate.

Comment: The onClick method can be used in onPostExecute?

Comment: OnClick can be set in onCreate. It will be called on when the button is clicked. You only have to do setText in onPostExecute since you have the text only then.

Comment: That means all my function should be write in the onPostExecute including the 2D arrays data?

Comment: Fetch and perform any operations in 2D array in doInBackground and display the text in onPostexecute